# Implementing Layouts According to Screen Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm wondering if it's possible to use different layouts based on a phone's screen size (not tablets, watches, etc.). I've already taken a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) article, but don't seem to be having any success implementing what it suggests. Just for context, I'm using a ConstraintLayout for all of my layouts. I originally designed my UI using a Pixel 3 XL, and when I try to run my application on any other device, the UI looks distorted, its elements aren't anywhere they should be, and everything is just awful.

How would I go about making and assigning layouts for each screen size? Is there something else I could do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Inso is right, you can just save different versions of your resourses in different versions of your res/ subfolders (like layout-1280x720 or drawable-1920x1080). This not only applies to layout files but also to drawables and any other resource directory and you can create different versions not only by screen resolution but also by device API screen size and others.

I recommend you read the following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?hl=de#AlternativeResources) that explains all that is possible.

It might also be that you just chose the wrong layout type for your app. you should check the available documentation on layout types (there is a bunch out there) and see if maybe ConstraintLayout may have been the wrong pick.

I also recommend having a set of different virtual devices (from the emulator) having different screen sizes and running different APIs so you can test every now and them how your app performs under differnet conditions

Answer (score 2):

Google recommend to create different res/layout directory for specific pixels, such as res/layout-1024x720，res/layout-1280x720，res/layout-1920x1080 etc..